# Traveling with creatine without airport/customs hassle

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airport-security

I'm following a [creatine](https://examine.com/supplements/Creatine/) supplementation regimen and take 5 grams every day. Creatine is a white powder that might look to [lazy bored teenagers or resentful proles](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42141/can-a-shower-hose-be-taken-on-planes-worldwide-without-hassle/42173#42173) like some illegal drug.

I don't have a doctor's note for this because creatine isn't some controlled substance, and I don't have a bottle with a "creatine" label on it because mine came in a [large bag](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00E9M4XEE) and I'll only need ~100g max.

Would I risk getting in trouble with the TSA or other airport authorities?  How should I package the powder? Airports I'll be flying through include San Jose, Vancouver, Hong Kong, Phuket, Singapore, San Francisco and possibly Newark.

[image: creatine white powder]

Comment: Because of some medical problems, I normally buy generic Acetaminophen in 500 caplet containers. My shopping list for international travel includes a much smaller container of Tylenol. Why not buy just enough for your travel in a properly labeled container?

Comment: One of the problems with creatine (for bodybuilding) is that it comes in rather large containers. If you're only traveling for a few days you'll need a fraction of the container which might take up a ton of room otherwise in your suitcase. That's why it's more difficult to buy a small amount as you recommended just for travel, and most people just put a small amount in a ziplock bag.The recommendation to buy creatine pills below is an awesome idea and works better I think in this scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My bodybuilding friend travels within Europe with protein and creatine powder in his carry-on and has never had issues. Drugs are usually detected by drug-sniffing dogs, not random employees, so you shouldn't be afraid of "getting caught". Remember there's no law against carrying random powders, just against carrying illegal drugs.

However I wouldn't try the above when travelling to paranoid countries such as UAE, where people have been known to get arrested for carrying poppy seeds. In that case I'd recommend carrying the creatine in sealed tablets or some other clearly packaged form.